# Ruby on Rails application deployment on multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are the useful gems or softwares that will help deployment of RoR 3.2 application on the clouds?

There is no specific requirements since I just want to get experience with it. But I am thinking of Amazon EC2 as a primary environment to test the application. The goal is to deploy it in the multiple servers.

I guess the most naive way would be launching the same application on multiple servers at the same time, but that will requires a lot of manual restart/reboot which requires a lot of human resources.

Is a single application of ruby on rails just not suited well for deployment on multiple servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Capistrano (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) to communicate with multiple EC2 instances on AWS.

We use Chef (https://github.com/opscode/chef) to do the system management configuration.
You can get cookbooks for various applications that you want to install (eg nginx, monit, logrotate...) from Opscode (http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks)

You will need both Capistrano and Chef to setup and deploy to AWS.

Puppet is another system management configuration that you can use too. (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet)

Answer (score 0):

This is what Capistrano is for.

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/